# Compare elements in 2d array java?

Tags: java, arrays

If I have a two-dimensional array in Java:

```
1 0 0
0 1 0
1 0 1
```

And I have another of smaller or equivalent size:

```
1 0
0 1
```

How would I find matches where an area of values inside the first array is equal to the second array?

---

For example, if we split the first array into multiple different small arrays that each have the same dimensions as the second...

This would be the top left corner:

```
1 0
0 1
```

Here's the top right corner:

```
0 0
1 0
```

And so on...

How can I check if one of the first array's splits is equal to the second array

---

This is the code I use to define arrays:

```
public static void main(String argv[])
{
    int a[][] = { {1,0,0}, {0,1,0}, {1,0,1} };
    int element[][] = {{1,0}, {0,1}};
}
```

And then I try to use `Arrays.deepEquals(Array1, Array2)` to compare them.

Comment: this is not totally clear. 1 you want to test all sub-arrays of the first ? 2 what have you coded yet ?

Comment: I believe OP is trying to see if the smaller 2x2 array is a "part" of the bigger 3x3 array.  Part being the 4 2x2 arrays you can get from a 3x3. Only a guess though.

Comment: @PJA Purpose of Stack Overflow is to be *searchable repository* of programming questions and answers, so other could use to find solutions for their programming problems. If your question isn't written in a way which makes it clear you should [edit] it and provide more information in question itself. While links are great as *additional* source of information they can't be its *main* source, since they can break easily which will make your question useless for others (also we can't find your question based on by content from link - especially if it is video).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cut the array at x and y by looking at the values in [x, y] to [x + 1, y + 1].

```
public static int[][] cut(int[][] source, int x, int y)
{
    return new int[][]{
        new int[]{ source[x][y], source[x + 1][y] },
        new int[]{ source[x][y + 1], source[x + 1][y + 1] }
    };
}
```

Note this function assumes your array is square. Then iterate over the large array, cutting and comparing. Since our cut function takes a 2x2 array, we stop before x and y get to the edge of the large array (Hence the x < large.length - 1).

```
public static boolean test(int[][] large, int[][] small)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < large.length - 1; x++)
        for (int y = 0; y < large[0].length - 1; y++)
        {
            int[][] part = cut(large, x, y);
            if (Arrays.deepEquals(part, small))
                return true;
        }
}
```